# Android logcat message: SurfaceTextureClient

Tags: android, android-logcat

My app is generating this logcat message almost every second:

```
SurfaceTextureClient [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5e774a58) fps:2.00, dur:1496.57, max:499.96, min:498.21
```

and it's just a hello world with a custom logo in the actionbar and saves things in SharedPreferences. My activity layout is a LinearLayout with two edittexts and one button. No strange things.
This is the only style I use:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>
```

I've searched in google but I have found nothing.

When I touch the button this appears:

```
Provider/Settings invalidate [system]: current 1 != cached 0
Provider/Settings from db cache, name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
```

It's annoying.

**EDIT**

Maybe is my smarphone. I've installed the same app in a tablet and the messages don't appear. Maybe I have touch something in settings? It's very strange. (My phone is a Jiayu 3gs with Android 4.2.1, but until today nothing wrong had happened).

Ok, the message appears in the general log so it's not associated with my app.

I'm starting to think that I have a virus. I have a lot of messages of this kind without doing anything in the phone:

```
ADB_SERVICES create_local_service_socket() name=shell:ls -l /
ADB_SERVICES adb: unable to open /proc/14420/oom_adj
ADB_SERVICES adb fdevent_process list (31) (20) (77) 
ADB_SERVICES closing because is_eof=1 r=1 s->fde.force_eof=0
SurfaceFlinger [SurfaceFlinger] fps:2.002652,dur:1498.01,max:499.41,min:499.22
UsbDeviceManager onReceive - BATTERY_CHANGED - mPlugType: 2, mSettingUsbCharging: false, mConnected: true, mSettingUsbBicr: false
```

And I have a lot of files in my `/` with date creation of `1970-01-01 01:00`. Files like init, init.modem.rc, init.rc, init.usb.rc, ..., emmc@android, ..
Maybe I'm just paranoid.

Furthermore I can't access to all options in "Developer options settings". This is all I can see:

[image]

Comment: do you use any library?

Comment: No, It's just one activity and one layout and I'm using Intellij. And the message it's not an error (it's green).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different phones have different kind and amount of log messages. Not much you can do about it, besides filtering the output based on the tag you use.

Comment: I don't think this indicates a virus. At my company we have many different Android phones, and there are huge differences between logging. Some Samsung devices for instance seem to constantly be logging stuff, while not that much seems to happen.

Comment: Regarding the ADB services, you have your device connected to your computer to read the log, which happens via ADB. I think this accounts for the ADB_SERVICES logs.

Try to disconnect your device and get a log via developer settings. Wait until it obtained it, and send it to your own email. Then inspect if you still see the adb messages. That way you can know for  sure what it caused it. Note that the log stays there for a short while so keep an eye on the time of the events.

Comment: That's another problem not related to this one. I just can see this options in "Developer settings" (see my edit)

Comment: You can also install [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) to get the log without being connected to USB. About the missing options, what version of android are you running?

Comment: But aLogcat is awkard to use for debugging. About the missing options: I've solved it.

Comment: I understand :) How did you solve the missing options? I could not find any solutions on StackOverflow, so you might ask the question, and answer it yourself so others are able to find it.